# Draw jpanel at double position

Tags: java, swing, animation, game-physics

I have a jpanel that I repaint in a step event. It takes a cars position x and draws it. This works with integers but I'd like to use a double. The car objects x and y are needed to be doubles because I want to rotate and accelerate in a direction. Any ideas? Here's my current code:

```
public class Map extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private void step() {
        for(int i = 0; i <cars.length; i++) {
            Car car = cars[i];       
            car.move();
            repaint(car.getX()-1, car.getY()-1, car.getWidth()+2, car.getHeight()+2);  
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. One possibility is for you to use doubles in your program's *model*, the classes that describe the state of your system, and use ints (by casting or rounding) in the view -- your GUI graphics code -- when displaying the state of the model.
2. Another is for you to consider using classes that implement the Shape interface, such as `Rectangle2D`, `Ellipse2D`, and `Path2D` as these use double or float specifiers for positioning
3. Your current code is broken in that the code is called on the Swing event thread, but appears to attempt to animate within a for loop. That's not going to work, and will only show the starting and finishing state of the animation due to it blocking the Swing event thread. Instead use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive the animation.